# Samsung S8 always on display timeout?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

For the purposes of this question, I want to clarify my terminology.

**Always on display** The screen feature Samsung has when the screen dimly stays on to show you stuff even when the phone screen is "off". This screen shows you simplified notifications.

**Lock screen** This is the screen you see that says "Swipe screen to unlock". This screen appears after hitting the power button. The always on display disappears and the lock screen appears. This screen shows you detailed notifications.

**Security screen** This screen appears after swiping from the lock screen. This will ask to type in the pin or enter a pattern to unlock the device.

The issue I have is the time between the lock screen and the always on display. I see I have a notification on the always on display. I'll hit the power button to go to the lock screen to read the notification. The lock screen then only stays up for 2 seconds (not exaggerating, I timed it) and then transitions back to the always on display. This is super frustrating. Trying to read a notification and boom here comes the always on display.

I have the screen timeout set for 2 minutes. I have the security lock timeout set for 5 minutes. I can't find any other settings for this.

How can I extend the amount of time the phone takes to move from the lock screen back to the always on display?

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I have the exact same question

Comment: @wellspokenman No, I did not find an answer.